# Display Output Profiler

Tags: super-admin

ExpressionEngine v2.9.2

I'm logged in as a Super Admin and I'm trying to turn on 'Display Output Profiler' in the admin control panel, but it will not save the change.

I suspect that this is because the config file does not have the permission set to allow writing, but I can't find which file to change permissions on, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

that should probably be config.php in /system/expressionengine/config/config.php
it should be 666 according to the docs

Comment: That is what I thought, but I've tried changing the permissions for that file, and it doesn't make any difference. I guess there is something else wrong.

Comment: Did you develop the site yourself? It might be a custom config file like master config. you can edit your index.php file too, and set 
$config['template_debugging'] = 'y';

Comment: no, and it does have a slightly odd setup, I'll give the index.php file a try, thanks